# Can I use Kolmogorov–Smirnov test on my Data?

Tags: distributions, continuous-data, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I am not good in statistics so I desperately need your help.

So I have this dataset of distributions, and I want to know if I can use the KS-test on it. the Idea is saying that the feature's distribution 1 in case 1 is different than its distribution 2 in case 2.
For example, let s take the feature "size" in two cases: case1, case2

The distribution 1 (in case 1) looks like this:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,132,33,1200,0,0,98,208,56,0,0,0,....]
```

The distribution 2 (in case 2) looks like this:

```
[52215,2132,933,11200,0,0,13245,4208,309,0,34000,0,....]
```

and so on,

each number represent the total size in one second, and the null hypothesis, is that **distribution 1 and distribution 2 follow identical distribution** so the point is rejecting it by having a less than 1% as a p-value (that s what I understood please correct me if I am wrong)

I read that KS-test is applied on continuous distributions, is the one I have  continuous?? how to know if your distribution is continuous?

If I can't apply the KS, what else can I apply? mentioning that I work with Python..

Comment: The KS doesn't apply, but you could use the same statistics in a permutation or randomization test.

Answer (score 4):

If "size", or any other feature, is not constrained to a countable set of values (i.e., you can enumerate them like a list...although the list might be infinitely long), then you have a continuous rv.

You can certainly apply the [K-S test here for generalized differences](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat464/node/54). Its easy for two samples, but if you are trying to test for general difference in 3+ distributions, you should use a computational approach:

1. Your null hypothesis is $H_0: F_1=F_2....=F_N$ for distributions $F_i$ pertaining to your particular feature for each of $i=\{1...N\}$cases, each of size $n$
2. Under the null, we can assume the the data from each case **came from the same population or distribution**, therefore, you will be combining your data into a single "bucket" for purposes of testing your hypothesis. Thus you will have one "null population" of size $N\times n$
3. Here's the computational part:
4. (a) Randomly sample **with replacement** from the "null population" to create N groups of size $n$. Let's call this new set of data a *replication*, designated $R_1$.
5. (b) Find the **largest** vertical difference between the groups of empirical CDFs (similar to what you do with the 2 sample KS test, but you will now have to determine, for each value of your feature, the maximum value of the group of ECDFs and the minimum value of the ECDFs, then find the maximum value of the difference of these two values across all values of "size"), lets call this value $K_1$
6. (c) Repeat this 1000 or so times using a computer (more if possible), to get 1000 $K$ values.
7. (d) Now, calculate the $K$ value of your actual results (i.e, the actual N groups you observed), call this $K_a$
8. Determine the number of $K$ values such that $K\geq K_a$ and divide by the total number of K values. This is the $p$-value of your test. Treat it as any other $p$-value.

As you can see, this is a relatively straightforward test (formally called a resampling or Bootstrap hypothesis test), that substitutes intensive calculation for complex (often intractable) mathematics. It is also flexible, since you can easily adapt to varying  numbers of samples, varying sample sizes, etc.

Comment: Isn't the chi-square test a suitable replacement for Kolmogorov-Smirnov and Anderson-Darling tests in cases when data is not only continuous? At least, this is stated in the following paper by Ricci (http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Ricci-distributions-en.pdf, p. 16): "The chi-square goodness of fit test can be applied either to discrete distributions or continuous ones while the Kolmogorov-Smirnov and Anderson-Darling tests are restricted to continuous distributions."

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh yes, the Chi-square test is generally useful. The issue here is to detect "general" differences amongst the distributions without a reference distribution. The K-S test or chi-squared can be used for 2 distributions, but when you have 3, 4, 5... distributions, you loose the symmetry of a two-sample comparison.

Comment: I see. Thank you for clarification. I was curious about this question, as currently I'm working, among other things, on distribution fitting for EDA part of my research. Would appreciate, if you could provide feedback on my relevant question here on CV: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112631/determining-probability-distribution-for-datasets-with-missing-values.

Comment: @Aleksandr The chi-square ignores the ordering in the data, so loses a lot of power.

Comment: Eupraxis -- the first sentence of your answer is not quite correct. Consider a distribution that is 40% $0$, 40% $1$ and 20% $\text{U}(0,1)$. It is not constrained to a countable set of values, yet it is not continuous and under it, the K-S test doesn't have the "usual" null distribution. But it's a good answer.

Comment: @Glen_b: Thank you for clarification. I will read up on this.

Comment: @Glen_b Yea, I struggled with whether I should try to describe a "mixed" random variable...decided to omit, but you are correct, if there are "dirac-deltas" in the PMF, then KS will have issues.